# Flutter barcode_scan unable to get a response

Tags: flutter

I'm using the barcode_scan package to get barcode information.

```
barcode_scan: ^3.0.1
```

I have a super simple test scenario set up like this:

```
ScanResult result = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
print(result.rawContent);
```

I see the barcode scanner screen show up, and it appears to detect the barcode because as soon as I focus on the barcode it pauses and the closes the barcode scanner screen. however, it never reaches the line below `print(result.rawContent);` I'm not seeing any errors either. I've tried wrapping the whole thing in a try catch just to see, but it never entered the catch. It's like it just doesn't return anything from the `await BarcodeScanner.scan()` call and just aborts completely.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: have u added camera permission by <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> in manifest.xml?

Comment: having the same problem without any solution over the internet with 3.00 and 3.01

Comment: the version 2.0.2 is working until now

Comment: I am having the same problem, any solution until now?

Comment: Could you make a GitHub sample and I could help you?

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same issue on my existing project was created on old version of flutter, when I create new project with last version of flutter(1.12.x-pre) it is work find.

- flutter(1.12.x-pre) down can use barcode_scan: ^2.x.x
- flutter(1.12.x-pre) up can use barcode_scan: ^3.x.x

It is not bug, I just found new issue on barcode_scan.

Issue: https://github.com/mintware-de/flutter_barcode_reader/issues/261#issue-643704981

I'm a newer of flutter.

Answer (score 2):

I solved downgrading `barcode_scan` from `3.0.1` to `2.0.0`.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In the barcode_scan Flutter package Getting Started section, there are a few setup steps that you have to follow (if you haven't done so already)

If you are testing this on an **android** device, try these following steps:

1. you will need to add the camera permission App-level AndroidManifest.xml in the debug folder. In my test app, I placed it under 
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
2. In the **project-level build.gradle file**, be sure to check the ext.kotlin_version is the same as the one listed, which at the time of writing is **1.3.61**
3. Check your app-level build.gradle as well to make sure it has the lines listed in the Getting Started Guide.
4. Lastly (I know you already did this but), depend on the package in the pubspec.yaml file.

If you are testing this on an **iOS** device, try these following steps:

1. Make sure to add the following code for camera usage description in the Info.plist file.

```
<dict>
    <!-- ... -->
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Camera permission is required for barcode scanning.</string>
    <!-- ... -->
</dict>
```

Source: https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan#-readme-tab-

Comment: Thanks, yeah I followed all of the setup steps. I noticed that if I roll back to a 2.x version it works, but none of the 3.x versions are working. I've tried the stable, beta, and master channels for flutter, but still the same results.

Comment: @cloudwalker You are correct. There seems to be a problem with the 3.x versions. The 2.x works without issues.